# Retaining the same tab bar in a new view

Tags: ios, objective-c, tabs

I am a newbie with regards to IOS Development, so I really need help regarding this matter. I have been working in a program where in a have a slide bar as well as a tab bar.  However, when I click an item from the slide bar, it goes to the new view and the tab bar disappears.  I tried embedding the new view into a navigation controller and  adding a push segue between my tab bar controller a to the new view.. but still, tab bar won't show up.

What will I do to retain or use my existing tab bar in my new view? so, it will be visible to the new view.

Thanks! your help is very much appreciated. :)

Answer (score 0):

First, you gotta perform a push, not a modal. Then, you could use this method hidesbotTombarWhenPushed in the view controller that pushes, that should do the trick.

If not, maybe you can clarify more or post some code :)

Answer (score 0):

This may be because of you are not adding tabview controller as the window's root view controller in *AppDelegate*. Check the sample code below

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    viewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];
    searchController = [[SearchController alloc]initWithNibName:@"SearchController" bundle:nil];
    navCtrl1 = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:viewController];
    navCtrl2 = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:searchController];
    NSMutableArray *viewControllersArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    [viewControllersArray addObject:navCtrl1];
    [viewControllersArray addObject:navCtrl2];
    tabController = [[UITabBarController alloc]init];

    tabController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: navCtrl1 ,navCtrl2,nil];
    self.window.rootViewController = tabController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;

}
```